# MySQL can't connect to another server with ERROR 2003 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, connections

I have two servers:

- server1: 192.168.0.2
- server2: 192.168.0.3

They are both CentOS 6. I installed MySQL on both two servers.

I can ping server2 from server1

```
$ ping 192.168.0.3
```

I can connect MySQL server with host on server2

```
# (server2)
$ mysql -h 192.168.0.3 -u root -p
```

But I can't connect server2 from server1:

```
# (server1)
$ mysql -h 192.168.0.3 -u root -p
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.3' (113)
```

My `my.cnf` on server2:

```
# /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
...
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Off course restart it: `service mysqld restart`

My `iptables` on server2:

```
# /etc/sysconfig/iptables
...
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
...
```

Off course restart it: `service iptables restart`

I did this on server2:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When did `mysql_secure_installation` on server2, I allowed remote root connect.

Everything I think good. But can't connect server2 from remote. Why?

Comment: Have you verified that it's listening on 192.168.0.3? `netstat -an | grep tcp | grep 3306`

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Yes. The result: `tcp 0 0 192.168.0.3:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`.

Comment: Have a look in  your my.cnf file and comment out if there is a line containing `skip-networking`. Temporarily stop firewalls on both servers `sudo service iptables stop` and `sudo service ip6tables stop`. Once this is done, can you post any error messages you get when trying to connect?

Comment: @thatsaru In my my.cnf file there isn't a `skip-networking` setting. Even I stoped the firewall the result was the same. I think the reason is my two virtual machines network setting.

Comment: @foo_bar - didn't realise you had virtual machines. So are these both on your desktop/laptop? Also, which virtual technology are you using VMWare/VirtualBox etc.

Comment: @thatsaru  I have resolved the problem. After I run `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';` on the second server, I can access it from first server. I am using VirtualBox.